# Is this correct usage of move semantics

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have a function call

```
class MyClass {
    static std::string getName(void) {
        return getMyName(void); // Returning by value as well
    }
};
```

Now if I use this function in constructor of a class

```
class AnotherClass {
public:
    AnotherClass(void) :
        m_name(std::move(MyClass::getName())) {} // 1. std::move used

    const std::string& name(void) const {   // 2. Should I use std::string&& (without consts)
                                            //    .... but I also need to make sure value cannot be changed (e.g, name() = "blah";)
                                            //    if std::string&& will be used should I use it simply by calling name() to call function using move or should I leave it as is?
        return m_name;
    }
private:
    std::string m_name;
}
```

Is this correct usage of move semantics? How can I ensure a function is using move semantics?

I am trying to learn to implement efficiency by move semantics so apology if its dumb question.

I have checked

[What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)

http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html

[Is this correct usage of C++ 'move' semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148341/is-this-correct-usage-of-c-move-semantics)

a great explanation but need clarafication on ensuring if function is using move semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `std::move` here:

```
   m_name(std::move(MyClass::getName())) {} // no need to use std::move
```

`getName()` returns a copy, which is already an rvalue.

Just do this like you normally would:

```
   m_name(MyClass::getName()) {}
```

The move constructor will be used automatically, if it is needed at all.  (The compiler may very well omit the copy altogether and construct the return value of `MyClass::getName()` directly into `m_name`, which is even better).

As for this:

```
const std::string& name() const { return m_name; }
```

there is no need to do anything special here either.  You don't want `m_name` to be changed, so you shouldn't use `std::move`, and you should be using a regular const lvalue reference.

The most common situation where you need `std::move` is when you are creating your own move constructor:

```
class AnotherClass {
public:
    AnotherClass(AnotherClass &&that) :
        m_name(std::move(that.m_name))
    {
    }
};
```

This is because even though `that` is declared as an rvalue reference, inside the constructor, `that` behaves like a regular lvalue reference.

Comment: so is this OK to rely on compiler to "automatically" use move? I mean for C++03 the first m_name(MyClass::getName()) would be return value and make temp objs? As said, compiler "MAY VERY WELL", because I am working with shared library (non-compiled) so I am not sure what compiler would be used ?

Comment: @dev-inside: If it is possible for it to use a move constructor, then it will.  Are you wanting to get an error if moving is not supported?

Comment: Yes I am looking for such a way.

Comment: @dev-inside: If your `std::string` didn't have a move constructor, then using `std::move()` would catch it.